# Where does the root reducer come from in this redux react example and how does dispatch knows which reducer to go?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to go through redux react tutorial and I am wondering where `rootReducer` come from

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

Does `combineReducers` auto export `rootReducer`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo?file=/src/redux/store.js

Second question in

`/components/AddTodo.js`

```
handleAddTodo = () => {
  this.props.addTodo(this.state.input);
  this.setState({ input: "" });
};
```

`handleAddTodo` calls the `addTodo` action

`/redux/actions.js`

```
export const addTodo = content => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: {
    id: ++nextTodoId,
    content
  }
});
```

Which just returns an object

But what connects the `addTodo` to the reducer itself in `/reducers/todos.js`?

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {

      .....
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does combineReducers auto export rootReducer?

Yes it does

```
export default combineReducers({ todos, visibilityFilter });
```

is enough

> What connects the addTodo to the reducer itself in /reducers/todos.js?

The dispatch function, when you call this:

```
this.props.addTodo(this.state.input);
```

under the hood you're actually running something like this:

```
dispatch(addTodo(this.state.input))
```

Comment: but how does `dispatch(addTodo(this.state.input))` know to use function in `todos.js` and not function in other file like in `visibilityFilter.js` ?

Comment: it depends on which one you added in line no. 3 in AddToDo.js
```import { addTodo } from "../redux/actions";```

Comment: so it's actually using the one in actions.js

Answer (score 1):

This is the pseudo code for `combineReducers`:

```
function combineReducers({ reducer1, reducer2 }) {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'reducer1') return reducer1(state.reducer1, action);
    if (action.type === 'reducer2') return reducer2(state.reducer2, action);
  }
}
```

It's not entirely correct, esp. the returning part, but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Basically, what it does is to create one big reducer that works as if both reducers are combined into one. A reducer is, as you may already know, *one function* that accepts the previous state and the action, and returns the next state.

Second question: `connect` does the trick. Once you connect your `addTodo` prop to the store, the store which already is connected to the reducer, will call the reducer (again, ONE BIG function) with the `(prevState, action)` value. `action` will be the return value of `addTodo` action generator method.

And the reducer does the rest, i.e. checks if the matching action type (in this case, `ADD_TODO`) exists and does what it does.